# Android onBackPressed() in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment where I have to implement the onBackPressed() method but it does not work

```
public void onBackPressed(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
          .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
          .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
          .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
          .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{

    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
{
      ((MainActivity)PaymentFragment.this.getActivity()).showOrders();
}
        }).create().show();
}
```

I have 3 methods:

onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

onCreateView():

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    btnPayment = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btnPayPal);

    btnPayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(SessionManager.totalPayment>0){
                PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(SessionManager.totalPayment), "EUR", "SSSSS",
                        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PaymentActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }else{
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage(R.string.empty_cart)
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            }
                        });
    return root;   //view
}
```

onActivityResult() - Here I go to the PayPal activity

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                String confirmation = confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4);
...
```

I want to make a dialog box where if user confirms that he wants to exit, it goes to the showOrders Fragment. In which method should I include the onBackPressed() method and how can I change the code to work for fragments? I have read several articles on StackOverflow but it did not answer my questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
fragment.getView().requestFocus();
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ){
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```